# Node.js console.log not logging in terminal

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple app where I'm trying to log to the console (terminal where I started Node, not the the browser console). Express seems to execute the route since I can see the response in my browser.
Also the logging in the app.listen(..) seems to work, but I don't see any logs afterwards.

```
'use strict';

// 3rd-party dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dbSetup = require('./db-setup');


// Application config
const LOCAL_APP_PORT = 8080;
const PUBLIC_APP_PORT = process.env.PUBLIC_APP_PORT || LOCAL_APP_PORT;
global.dbType = process.env.DB_TYPE;

// Sanity check for debugging
console.log("local app port:", LOCAL_APP_PORT);
console.log("public app port:", PUBLIC_APP_PORT);
console.log("db type:", global.dbType);

// Database setup for either MongoDB or Postgres
dbSetup(global.dbType);

// Express middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

// Import routes
//const index = require('./routes/index');
//const owner = require('./routes/owner');
//const shop = require('./routes/shop');
//const product = require('./routes/product');

// Set up express routes
app.use('/',(req,res,next) => {
  console.log("This is not showing on the terminal.");
  res.send("This is sent to the browser");
  next();
})

//app.use('/owner', owner);
//app.use('/shop', shop);
//app.use('/product', product);

app.listen(LOCAL_APP_PORT, () => {
  console.log('App started ...');
});
```

**EDIT**: Solved. Problem was my app was basically available on two ports at the same time. One the the public port however it was not showing any logs...

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpVEK.png)

Comment: your code works as intended. is there any thing missing on the snippet you posted?

Comment: Problem was my app was basically available on two ports at the same time. When accessing on the public port however it was not showing any logs, on the local port it does show logging.

Comment: so you got it fixed right? if not let me/us know what is left